# 404 on Azure but not on local development machine

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core-rc1

I migrated a MVC project from Asp.net 5 RC1-final to core 1.0.1. On my Development machine everything runs perfect but when I publish it to Azure WebApp I get a 404 on every route. I tried to debug the site and it seems that the View can not be found. Any idea what it could be or how I can get a more detailed error report?

Comment: diagnostics logging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error was that I did not add the Views under publishOption in the project.json.

Before:

```
"publishOptions": {
"include": [
  "wwwroot",
  "web.config"
]
},
```

Now:

```
"publishOptions": {
"include": [
  "wwwroot",
  "Views",
  "web.config"
]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to see whether **File Publish Option** Remove Additional Files At Destination is checked. If it is not checked, check it and publish. It should delete all files at the destination and publish the upgrade.

Comment: But I assumed the problem is now solved, with explanation below